# Is there any way to write value to global registry from Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: c#, installation

I'm trying to write some byte array specified for each computer into Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\[Manufacturer] during installation and every time my program starts it need to read value from Registry to conformity check. When I had tried to write value from my program it had worked fine but when tried to put exactly the same code to overrided Install method of my extended Installer class it was silently executed but no Registry value was added. I found out that "In Visual Studio 2017/2019, registry settings are stored in a private location ... these entries are not stored in the global registry", maybe this is the reason, but I don't khow how to edit global Regystry using Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Have you tried creating a .reg file and adding it to the installer?

Comment: @tgolisch i don't understand what file I need to use as assemblyFile to create .reg file. If i try to reg exe file of my program I get message with "it is not a valid .NET assembly". Also .reg files that i tried to create from Windows Registry Editor had static values, I mean that saved exactly that value I put but I need to change this value from computer to computer

Comment: ok I tried to create .reg file not from default win cmd but from visual studio cmd, it gave me message like "no types were registered", I changed ComVisible in AssemblyInfo.cs that is in Properties of the Project to true, after this I successfully created .reg file and manyally imported it into the setup project by opening Registry Editor, right clicking by "Registry on the Target Machne" and clicking "Import..." in opened menu. Now installer writes some info about my classes into HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT but still doesn't write needed byte[] value to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\\[Manufacturer]

Comment: reg files are just text files. You can edit them with notepad. If it works on your machine, use regedit to find a working byte[] setting (eg. maybe the ones your program needs), export it, then use notepad to edit / copy / imitate the format or content.  I recall the installer had an option to import reg settings.  If not, I've had to modify installers or write a setting manager program to do that.  .NET does have some libraries for working with the registry, but they require admin access, while the program is running.

Comment: Btw, your question sounds similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497627/add-registry-key-to-hkcu-runonce-for-every-user-from-visual-studio-setup-project?rq=1